# What is so special about 24 characters string while calling base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString

Tags: string, go, base64

What is so special about a string that is 24 characters long?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []string{"24CharacterStringppppppp", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "25CharacterStringpppppppp", "23CharacterStringpppppp", "qwertyuiop"}

    for _, d := range data {
        _, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(d)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Failed to decode base 64 string %v, err: %v \n", d, err.Error())

        } else {
            fmt.Printf("No Error\n")
        }
    }
}
```

I just stumbled upon this, any string that is 24 characters long does not generate an error while calling `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString` any other length string does.

What am I missing?

Comment: Padding. You're missing the [padding] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia: Base64:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

> Because Base64 is a six-bit encoding, and because the decoded values are divided into 8-bit octets on a modern computer, every four characters of Base64-encoded text (4 sextets = 4*6 = 24 bits) represents three octets of unencoded text or data (3 octets = 3*8 = 24 bits). **This means that when the length of the unencoded input is not a multiple of three, the encoded output must have padding added so that its length is a multiple of four.**

24 is a multiple of 4, but 23 or 25 are not. But if you add 4 more characters, 28 is again a multiple of 4 which also generates no error.

So for example these inputs all generate `"No Error"` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/x8MLCkGc0eI)):

```
data := []string{"", "1234", "12345678", "123456789012"}
```

Comment: Amazing example! As far as my concerns have been, this level of base64 has been abstracted for me. I learned something from this :)  A lovely (& succinct) example that packs a lot of knowledge. Cheers.